# Migrate to Programmers / Stack Overflow Revisited

Tags: discussion, migration

It has been about a month since the migrate-away options were added as close-reasons to Code Review - [Migration paths to other sites](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/migration-paths-to-other-sites)

Since migrated-away posts are deleted on the source site after about 30 days, a month is about all the history we get to see the source posts. In addition, the SEDE data has just been refreshed today....

Let's revisit the statistics for this new feature. In the past month:

[image: Migrations Away]

There have been 9 migrations away. 3 to programmers, 5 to Stack Overflow, and 1 to DBA. DBA is not on our migration path ... out of interest.

Now, of those 9 migrations, how how many community members voted to migrate away? As far as I can tell, none!

All posts migrated away were migrated purely on the whim of a moderator, and not the community. Perhaps someone flagged the posts for migration, but, if flagging for migration is the way to move things, then why have the community migrate-away option at all?

So, if all posts are migrated by moderators anyway, why is there a migration path? It seems that ***every*** - ***single*** - ***migration*** 
required moderator intervention anyway, why not just make that the normal way to do things?

Comment: *required*? I'm not so sure about that. Moderators on Code Review might do a bit more than what is *required*. Hard to tell what would happen if moderators would do nothing. Also, I think the interesting question is how many rejections there are, as long as that number is kept down, I don't see "moderators doing the migrations and not the community" as a reason to remove the migration paths.

Comment: Without moderator intervention, those migrations would not have happened. "Required" is implied in that. The alternative is "no migration", not "community migration". The fact that all migrations succeeded is exactly why I think that mods should be doing the (already-too-many) migrations.

Comment: @SimonForsberg - as a moderator, you can see more detail on user voting, on any of those 9 posts was there a single vote to migrate away? The places where I expect to find these details in SEDE are "empty", implying that either the data is confidential, or non-existent.

Comment: That sounds to me like the problem is to educate the community, not the fact that we have migration paths. If the community would have migrated a lot of questions that would have been rejected, *then* we would have a problem.

Comment: Does the data indicate any failed migrations by the community? Because if the community hasn't actually misused migrations, then I don't see any reason to take away their ability to perform them.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - there has yet to be a community-migrated post. On the other hand, half of the posts migrated by moderators to Programmers, have now been deleted (not even our mods understand Programmer's scope - I confess, that when I was a mod, I did not understand it either, and still do not). The mods also migrated one question to Stack Overflow that has been rejected. See details here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/rejected

Comment: @rolfl I can't see that data until I reach 10k (or maybe 20k?) but thanks for the added info. (and the scope of Programmers eludes us all)

Answer (score 2):

### Reason

My guess is that it's because not many users here understand the migration paths, and if the question is good enough for migration. I have seen one question that was fit (IMO) for SO, but I just closed as off-topic instead, because I was not sure.

### Answers

> why not just make that the normal way to do things?

That would make normal users (e.g. me) feel unimportant and untrusted. At least, that's what I would feel if I lost privileges.